# How to encrypt lower case input

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I am trying to create a simple encryption scheme. The scheme is working fine when I take input of the plain text in uppercase. But when I take input of the plain text in lowercase, it is not decrypted correctly.
Can anyone help me to find out the solution?

Here is my code:

```
def generateKey(string, key):
    key = list(key)
    st = list(string)
    if len(string) == len(key):
        return(key,st)
    else:
        x=len(string) -len(key)
        if x>0:
            for i in range(x):
                key.append(key[i % len(key)])
        else:
            y=len(key)-len(string)
            for j in range(y):
                st.append("X")
    return("" . join(key),"" . join(st))


def cipherText(string, key):
    cipher_text = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i]== " ":
            x = ord(string[I])
            i+=1
            cipher_text.append(chr(x))
        else:
            abc = ord(string[i]) + ord(key[I])
            x = (abc + 2) % 26
            x += ord('A')
            cipher_text.append(chr(x))
    ci="" . join(cipher_text)
    rev = ""
    for i in ci:
        rev = i + rev
    return(rev)


def originalText(cipher_text, key):
    orig_text = []
    re_rev= ""
    for i in cipher_text:
        re_rev = i + re_rev
    for i in range(len(re_rev)):
        if re_rev[i]== " ":
            x = ord(re_rev[I])
            i+=1
            orig_text.append(chr(x))
        else:
            abc = ord(re_rev[i]) - ord(key[i]) + 26
            x = (abc - 2) % 26
            x += ord('A')
            orig_text.append(chr(x))
    return("" . join(orig_text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    string = input("Enter Plain Text: ")
    keyword = input("Enter Keyword: ")
    key,stri = generateKey(string, keyword)
    cipher_text = cipherText(stri,key)
    print("Ciphertext :", cipher_text)
    print("Original/Decrypted Text :",
        originalText(cipher_text, key))
```

Comment: Work on this `x += ord('A')` ...

Comment: Can you please suggest an alternative to this... I mean what should I use instead of this?

Comment: First, you need to define the input space after that look at the ord values of them, then you can see what you need to do...